# How to assign default role automatically for all dashboards in superset

Tags: apache-superset, druid

We have DASHBOARD_RBAC enabled in superset, it is showing roles menu but no roles are populated as like below.
[image]

I want to assign Gamma Role as default role for every dashboard which is published in superset programatically. When ever new dashboard is published, automatically Gamma role has to be assigned by default. How we can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.!